# cholesky_AAt throwing dimensions of L and B do not match

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numeric, scikits

I'm attempting to solve a linear system of equations (Ax = b) with the Cholesky method. A is a sparse diagonally dominant matrix.  However when attempting to solve, I get an error: "dimensions of L and B do not match".  I'm not incredibly familiar with Cholesky and am so far not able to figure out the issue.  The relevant code to reproduce is as follows:

```
from scikits.sparse.cholmod import cholesky_AAt
import scipy.sparse

row = 12
w = 2
h = 2

datab = [-0.1424664938036192, 0, 0, -0.10303063143932194, 0, 0, -0.040151087842721742, 0, 0, -0.043413238389510278, 0, 0]
dataA = [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654757, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654757, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.8660254037844386, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0]
rowA_i = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
colA_i = [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2]

A = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((dataA, (rowA_i, colA_i)), shape=(row, w*h))
b = np.array(datab)

factor = cholesky_AAt(A.T)
x = factor(A.T * b)
```

The specific error I'm seeing is:

```
CholmodError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-bf6984dae484> in <module>()
 23 from scikits.sparse.cholmod import cholesky_AAt
 24 factor = cholesky_AAt(A.T)
---> 25 x = factor(A.T * b)
 26 
 27 

scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx in scikits.sparse.cholmod.Factor.__call__ 
(scikits/sparse/cholmod.c:8036)()

 scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx in scikits.sparse.cholmod.Factor.solve_A 
 (scikits/sparse/cholmod.c:7913)()

 scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx in scikits.sparse.cholmod.Factor._solve 
(scikits/sparse/cholmod.c:9713)()

scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx in scikits.sparse.cholmod.Factor._solve_dense 
(scikits/sparse/cholmod.c:10126)()

scikits/sparse/cholmod.pyx in scikits.sparse.cholmod._error_handler 
(scikits/sparse/cholmod.c:3270)()

CholmodError: ../Cholesky/cholmod_solve.c:1082: dimensions of L and B 
do not match (code -4)
```

With my understanding of the Cholesky solver, this should work, but I 
can't tell more than that.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Add the full error / stack-trace (and a reproducible example).

Comment: Added data to reproduce the error and the full trace.  Let me know if you have any insights!

Comment: What are your versions of numpy, scipy, scikit-sparse and cholmod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code works with a (reasonable) modern setup**, although it needs an other import-style as scikit-sparse seems to be changed in this regard. (This fact also indicates that you are using an old version).

#### Code

Your code with some modified import and a print:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
from sksparse.cholmod import cholesky_AAt

row = 12
w = 2
h = 2

datab = [-0.1424664938036192, 0, 0, -0.10303063143932194, 0, 0, -0.040151087842721742, 0, 0, -0.043413238389510278, 0, 0]
dataA = [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654757, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.70710678118654757, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.8660254037844386, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0]
rowA_i = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
colA_i = [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2]

A = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((dataA, (rowA_i, colA_i)), shape=(row, w*h))
b = np.array(datab)

factor = cholesky_AAt(A.T)
x = factor(A.T * b)

print(x)
```

#### Output:

```
sascha@ubuntu-17:~/Documents$ python3 so_scikit_sparse.py
so_scikit_sparse.py:17: CholmodTypeConversionWarning: converting matrix of class csr_matrix to CSC format
  factor = cholesky_AAt(A.T)
[-0.28493299 -0.14570732 -0.05678221 -0.05012929]
```

So everything works fine! The reason for this warning is explained in the documentation and can be prohibited by changing the type of the sparse-matrix (hint: CSR / transpose / CSC).

This observation together with a short read of the docs make me believe you did everything correctly (in the code)!

The reason here is (probably) some changes in numpy, (scipy) and/or suitesparse as indicated in these issues @ github: [1](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse/issues/4), [2](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse/issues/27), [3](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse/issues/35)

My versions:

- numpy: `1.12.1-3`
- scipy: `0.18.1`
- scikit-sparse: `0.4.2`
- libsuitesparse-dev: `4.5.5-1`

The above is what you get by:

- using OS-packages with Ubuntu 17.10 for python3-numpy, python3-scipy
- using OS-packages for libsuitesparse-dev
- pip3 install scikit-sparse

Comment: Changing to use sksparse.cholmod did it!  Thanks so much, this was driving me crazy.